# Trying to get the name of a term in custom taxonomy called 'pwb-brand' by ID

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

I've been on this for a while now, trying to find something similar. And I bet there is - I just can't seem to find it.

Basically what I am trying to do is getting the name of a term located in a custom taxonomy by ID.

The taxonomy is called `pwb-brand`

The term ID is generated from an Advanced Custom Field `the_sub_field('varumarke')`

All I get in return is the ID of the term but I don't get the name as wished for.

```
<?php $brands = get_term_by('id', the_sub_field('varumarke'), 'pwb-brand'); ?>
<?php foreach( $brands as $brand ):
    echo '<h2>' . $brand->name . '</h2>';
endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: You don't need to use foreach loop. You are getting a specific term as an object. Check here:https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_by/#user-contributed-notes Try directly `echo $brands->name` without foreach.

Comment: So like this? `<?php $brand = get_term_by('id', the_sub_field('varumarke'), 'pwb-brand'); echo '<h2>' . $brand->name . '</h2>'; ?>` I still only get the ID in return not the name :)

Comment: Is the value from `the_sub_field` actually an ID?

Comment: It is, see accepted answer for rookie mistake :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rule-of-thumb with WordPress: Functions named `the_something` normally write to the output buffer directly, whereas their `get_something` counterparts return the value.

```
get_term_by('id', the_sub_field('varumarke'), 'pwb-brand');
```

You are effectively not passing any value for the second parameter here - because `the_sub_field` echos the value, and doesn't return anything.

You need to use `get_sub_field` here instead.

Comment: Oh my god. Can't believe I missed this. Was too focused on the other stuff to see that what I needed to do was to change from the to get. Works like a charm, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning $brands to the value returned from a single term with `get_term_by` - if you want an array of brands to loop over you need to get multiple terms with something like:

```
$brands = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'pwb-brand',
));
```

Then you loop over each $brand in $brands to get the name. Is the value from `the_sub_field` actually an ID? You should always dump out your variables at each stage to check that the value is what you expect and work backwards from there.

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump( $brands );
echo '</pre>';
die();
```